# Nested queries in Elastic search which should apply on all objects in nested array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Hi I have this document in ES with nested type:

```
{
         "id": "92210f7f-b8a4-4d55-877d-8708154aa004",
          "additionalData": {

              "devices_nested": [
                {
                  "version_string": "1"
                },
                {
                  "os_string": "Windows",
                  "version_string": "3"
                },
                {
                  "os_string": "Centos"
                }
              ]

          }
```

I want to do query that *additionalData.devices_nested* does not contain any element where *os_string* property does not exist that means I want to avoid such documents where some entries could have or not os_string property. Here is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "additionalData.devices_nested.os_string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "path": "additionalData.devices_nested"
    }
  }
}
```

But I always get the example document as result because at least one element satisfies query that there is *os_string* property.
Is it possible to make query which will return document where all elements in *devices_nested* has *os_string* property?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make query which will return document where all elements in devices_nested has os_string property?

Yes, it is posible. Instead of **must exist**, you have to use **must_not missing** approach.

In following query, the bool condition inside `nested` will match all documents that do not have `os_string` field in at least one of the nested objects, and then, the outside `must_not` query will exclude these documents. As a result, you'll get only documents that include `os_string` field in all nested objects:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "nested": {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "additionalData.devices_nested.os_string"
                        }
                    }
                }
              },
              "path": "additionalData.devices_nested"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```